# Actualizar Ruby y Rails de proyecto viejo para despliegue en Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy intentando realizar un despliegue en Heroku, de un proyecto en Rails 4.2.7.1 y con Ruby 2.1.6, que pasa. Al momento de realizar el despliegue en Heroku me lanza un error
`remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     An error occurred while installing ruby-2.1.6
remote:  !

remote:  !     Heroku recommends you use the latest supported Ruby version listed here:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
remote:  !

remote:  !     For more information on syntax for declaring a Ruby version see:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
remote:  !

remote:  !

remote:  !     Debug InformationCommand: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-18/ruby-2.1.6.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed unexpectedly:
remote:  !

remote:  !     gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
remote:  !     tar: Child returned status 1
remote:  !     tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed`

Estuve leyendo y es por la versión de Ruby que ya no tiene soporte en Heroku, busque en Internet para actualizar la versión de Ruby a 2.4.9 y al parecer si se actualizo pero cuando ejecuto `rails s` me salta otro error

> /home/siscoteli5/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
>   /home/siscoteli5/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
>   Exiting
>   /home/siscoteli5/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:125:in `is_a?': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Ya tengo rato busco y probando pero no logro actualizar la version de Ruby sin que la versión de Rails explote para poder hacer el despliegue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso que mencionas es un [error de compatibilidad](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25125) entre ruby 2.4 y versiones antiguas de rails, específicamente porque en ruby 2.4 unificó `Fixnum` y `Bignum` en una única clase `Integer`.
El error fue arreglado para rails 4.2.8, así que actualizando a esa versión debería arreglar tu problema (o ya que estarás en eso, mejor a la última 4.2-stable que es la 4.2.11.1, por cualquier problema de seguridad que haya en las versiones anteriores).
Ahhh y suerte con esa actualización, ya que siempre están llenas de problemas de incompatibilidad.

Answer (score 0):

Tal como menciona Alter, puedes actualizar las versiones, pero eso podría generar problemas de compatibilidad en tu código. Si aún así quieres hacerlo, puedes probar las distintas versiones de Ruby usando rvm, todas las instrucciones están en https://rvm.io/, mientras que para Rails lo que debes hacer es eliminar el Gemfile.lock y luego cambiar la versión de Rails en el Gemfile y darle bundle. Suerte.